# I used the terminal to change my password, but it's not applying the change

Tags: command-line, login, password

I changed my password using `sudo passwd`. It worked fine, with no errors, but my password hasn't been changed. I rebooted, but that didn't fix anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you really used command `sudo passwd` (with no additional argument), then you changed the password for the `root` account - not your user account. In Ubuntu, which locks the root account by default, this will have had the side effect of unlocking the root account.

To change your own user account password, you should simply type

```
passwd
```

and follow the prompts. You can reset the default status of the root account by deleting the (new) root password and locking it using

```
sudo passwd -dl root
```

---

To change a *different* user's account password, you *would* need sudo - but would follow the command by the account name:

```
sudo passwd otheruser
```

Comment: Really? Interesting. I always thought you had to change (or create) the root password by running `sudo passwd root`. This is a nice shortcut, if I can remember it.